# Chrome doesn't debug my asp.net project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, browser

I am using **Visual Std. 2017** and **Windows 7**. 
I have a project with `asp.net` and `c#`.

Debugging works with Internet Explorer, and does not with Chrome, Firefox or other browsers. It shows only empty page in Chrome and others.

How to debug in Chrome?

Comment: OK. What is your question?

Comment: Have you checked chrome console?

Comment: I guess you rather have to configure Visual studio to launch your app to chrome or configure your IIS to be able to call a url without putting visual studio in debug mode. Does this, answer your no-question ?

Comment: No it didn't answer my question.